# bitnami_wordpress update for https

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

This one doesn't have the obvious solution! This is AWS Lightsail Wordpress by Bitnami.

Problem: Load this Wordpress site to HTTPS:
http://morrisdigital.studio/   -->   https://morrisdigital.studio/ (with all the css etc)

*The database and UI don't match!*

In the database, we have:
[image]

**Which does not match the UI:**
[image]

**I tried:** Updating the siteurl and home to https://morrisdigital.studio/ , then restarted the server.
**What happened:** Nothing, of course, so I changed it back to http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/

So, WHERE is the actual place to update the links in the database?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

You can set the home and site url for WordPress in its configuration file (opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php)

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://morrisdigital.studio/ ');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://morrisdigital.studio/');
```

That change should update all the links in the application. You can find more information here:

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/configure-domain/